# Issue showing results with results other than a decimal datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server

The SQL query that I was using was set up to pull all values greater than or equal to 12.

```
WHERE CAST(Value AS DECIMAL(6,2)) >= 12.0
```

However, the result set now includes values that are not exclusively decimals. Some results are "> 40.3" instead of an actual decimal value, so I'm getting the error,

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

I believe the error is coming from the "> 40.3" results. If I need all values greater than or equal to 12.0, how can I tweak the query to include these "> 40.3" values or the like. "> 40.3" is still technically greater than 12.0, but I'm not sure how to script this out with a non-decimal datatype ("> 40.3 is essentially a VARCHAR).

Comment: You'll have to parse the strings with custom logic.

Comment: Thank you David. How exactly can I go about that?

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore values that are not numbers using `TRY_CAST()`:

```
WHERE TRY_CAST(Value AS DECIMAL(6,2)) >= 12.0
```

If your only "range" specifier is `>`, then you can use `replace()`:

```
WHERE TRY_CAST(REPLACE(Value, '> ', '') AS DECIMAL(6,2)) >= 12.0
```

However, I would suggest that you revise the data model so you have two columns, an upper bound and a lower bound.